# FATAL -- Hostname not supplied: 'api.vcap.me/services/v1/offerings'

Tags: service, cloud-foundry

all

Configure the echo service in cloudfoundry, the echo_gateway output console started as follows

```
[2013-03-07 09:53:56.135519] echo_gateway - pid=25534 tid=a837 fid=d765  
FATAL -- Hostname not supplied: 'api.vcap.me/services/v1/offerings' ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/ruby/1.9.1/gems/addressable-2.2.8/lib/addressable/uri.rb:2253:in `validate'|
ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/ruby/1.9.1/gems/addressable-2.2.8/lib/addressable/uri.rb:1193:in `port='|
ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/ruby/1.9.1/gems/em-http-request-1.0.0.beta.3/lib/em-http/http_options.rb:41:in `set_uri'|
ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/ruby/1.9.1/gems/em-http-request-1.0.0.beta.3/lib/em-http/http_options.rb:8:in `initialize'|
ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/ruby/1.9.1/gems/em-http-request-1.0.0.beta.3/lib/em-http/request.rb:7:in `new'|
ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/ruby/1.9.1/gems/em-http-request-1.0.0.beta.3/lib/em-http/request.rb:7:in `new'|
/home/zhangyunpeng/cloudfoundry/vcap/services/echo/vendor/cache/vcap-services-base-0346efd96d31/lib/base/catalog_manager_base.rb:24:in `create_http_request'|
/home/zhangyunpeng/cloudfoundry/vcap/services/echo/vendor/cache/vcap-services-base-0346efd96d31/lib/base/catalog_manager_v1.rb:130:in `advertise_service_to_cc'|
/home/zhangyunpeng/cloudfoundry/vcap/services/echo/vendor/cache/vcap-services-base-0346efd96d31/lib/base/catalog_manager_v1.rb:56:in `block (2 levels) in update_catalog'|
/home/zhangyunpeng/cloudfoundry/vcap/services/echo/vendor/cache/vcap-services-base-0346efd96d31/lib/base/catalog_manager_v1.rb:55:in `each'|
/home/zhangyunpeng/cloudfoundry/vcap/services/echo/vendor/cache/vcap-services-base-0346efd96d31/lib/base/catalog_manager_v1.rb:55:in `block in update_catalog'
```

In VMC, by VMC info --services, echo services option cannot be listed.

I think it is related to my Vcap environment, because of the same code, in colleagues can be.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to take a look at here: http://support.cloudfoundry.com/entries/20485171-How-to-Add-a-System-Service-to-OSS-Cloud-Foundry-Step-by-Step-guide.